# Measures of goodness of fit, to compare different fitting models and routines

Tags: goodness-of-fit

I realise that there is no catch-all method of assessing and quantifying goodness of fit -- otherwise we'd all be using and it and it would be well known.

In my undergraduate studies I was always taught the reduced-chi squared method as a means of testing the goodness of fit. However since progressing to postgraduate study and beyond, I have learnt there are several methods to quantify goodness of fit.

Usually i just want to compare different fitting routines. More often than not I know the exact physical solution to the system I am working with and such can simulate noiseless data, and fit it accordingly. I can fit this in many ways, scaling, form of the fit equation itself, scaled fitting, log fitting and so on. So my questions are

What is a good way to compare fit models, and decide which is the best?
How can one more generally choose which statistic to select when looking at the goodness of a fit? I.e. is Reduced-Chi Squared, more appropriate than the sum of squared residuals etc.

How do these compare against other measures such as confidence intervals / bands.

I am working in a physics setting, not as a statistician or in a big data environment. My business is fitting analytically derived models and fitting to laboratory measured data.

---

I am adding a little more information about the type of problems I am working with, as requested in the comments. I won't give specific function or data sets as, again, I'd like more general advice and not a specific answer to a specific problem.

More often than not I have data which is noisy (Johnson thermal noise) but follows a distinct functional form which can be analytically derived from first principles. Typically such models have around 3-5 parameters and it is the parameters themselves I am interested in.

Specifically I am dealing with (but not always) frequency spectrum where I have a dissipated power as a function of frequency bin -- to reiterate there is usually a distinct profile with some noise on top.

Comment: Can you describe your models and data further?

Comment: I can, absolutely. The reason I didn't include it was that I didn't want to bias any answers too much into a specific case. What kind of information do you need and I'll update my question.

Comment: I usually use RMSE and R-squared for general fitting tasks. RMSE acts like average-magnitude-of-error, and is from the early days when "absolute value" was intellectual horror as it had no continuous derivative.  R-squared (R2) tells me how much of the dependent data variance is explained by the model, which I calculate as "1.0 - (residual_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)". If the R-squared value is 0.87, the model explains 87 percent of the variance in the dependent data. I do run into specialty cases where I'm fitting to the lowest sum-of-squared percent error, but that is rare.

Comment: As you said, there's no single best way. So this question becomes answerable only in specific cases! Without knowing more about your problem, it would be hard to give you a good answer. What exactly are you trying to address? Is your goal prediction, inference, parameter estimation? What kind of data do you have, what kind of model(s) are you using?

Comment: Thanks both for the input. @mkt I will add some further details.

Comment: I've added some further details. If this is still too vague I will add an example, but again I don't want the answers and discussions here too tailored.